# checking if the form fields exist with have_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have simple form for user (form_for @user) signup with password field:

```
<div class="control-group"> 
  <%= f.label :password, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls"> 
    <%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'password_field' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my rspec/capybara test I want to check if this password field exists
I try:

```
it {should have_field("password")}
```

but it doesn't work.
The same with "user_password" (as this is this password field id) or "user[password]" (this is this field name)

Not sure if have_field is correct matcher to use, as capybara documentation doesn't explain what it is. WHat's the best way to test if form field exists?

Comment: I found out it didnt work because I should have used: it{page.should have_field("password"). But I dont understand why as I have set subject{page} and visit new_user_path.

Answer (score 3):

Your code didn't work because instead:

`it { page.should have_field("password") }`

you should use either

`specify { page.should have_field("password") }`

or

`it { should have_field("password") }`

Answer (score 1):

Here, [in reply to myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095628/rspec-have-field-raises-an-error-while-have-selector-return-success/14106310#14106310) I've solved the problem, explicitly using :type => :password in a spec.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `have_field` with `have_selector`.